# Testing if the zero element is part of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let H be the set of all polynomials of the form p(t) = a + bt2 where a and b are in R and b > a.

I know that this set is not closed under scalar multiplication and does not contain the zero vector. But I do not know how it does not contain the zero vector.

Answer (score 2):

If $a \not = 0$, then $p(t)$ is not the zero polynomial. But if $a = 0$, then $b > 0$, so $p(t)$ is not the zero polynomial.

Comment: Short, to the point.  I like it.

Comment: What else could you possibly do?

Comment: Admittedly, nothing much.  But I know I probably would've taken like 3-5 sentences just rambling on.

Comment: No way man, gotta get those points and get out.